# knnMatch requires k>1 to get good results?

Tags: opencv, sift, surf

I am using SURF and i am trying both

```
FlannBasedMatcher
```

and

```
BruteForceMatcher
```

I saw to get good matches I need to set

```
matcher.knnMatch(,,2); // with k=2 (At least)
```

If I set `k = 1` I don't get the first less distant match for that keypoint.
Are there any reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

knnMatch partitions your data in k groups. If k=1, you will put it in one big group.

With a single partition, it will be hard for the algorithm to figure out the distance to a second one. So there will be no distance to calculate at all.

Comment: I can understand it when using FlannBased, but when I use BruteForceBased it should compare each keypoint with each other! So I should get always 1 keypoint with less distance